# how to prevent all crawlers except good ones (google, bing, yahoo) access website content?

Tags: web-crawler

I just want to let Google, Bing, Yahoo crawl my website to build indexes. But I do not want my opposite website use crawling service to steal my website content. What should I do?

Comment: This will require the use of robots.txt. ServerFault.com is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: The OP is concerned with bad intended people that don't respect the robot.txt

Comment: may be going for some User-Agent black list can help to certain extent. (by redirecting to 404 (or something) for blacklisted user-agents.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent Google, etc., from indexing your website, but you cannot prevent a malicious crawler from doing that.

Comment: Right. A crawler can make itself look exactly like a legitimate user if it goes to enough trouble.

Comment: It's a complex problem but sure it can be solved or minimized.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try track browsing patterns - if you are getting lots of clicks or weird browsing patterns that wouldnt come from a human throw up a captcha page.

Answer (score 2):

try crawling google.com with a custom crawler and see what they do , you can do the same :). Browsing patterns is the key to your problem :).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try browsing patterns.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to detect the crawls but its difficult when we need to differentiate between good crawlers and bad ones. But there is a way to do this. Its actually you have to use the hidden link on your website this will detect the all crawlers and for good crawlers on the bases of user agent dont let them read the hidden links. This will help you lots not 100% but more then 70%. I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I want the world to be able to find me, but I want to be invisible? At least one of us is confused...

Comment: I just want to apply the white-list access control for crawling engines. Certainly I need my website are crawled by Google, Bing, Yahoo on its title, description but no content. Other malicious crawling system do not obey the popular rules, so that our information can be stolen without permission.
Thanks for your answer, but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of crawler
 1. Renderless crawler that can request your website content without using any other technologies such as css, javascript and of course it's renderless
 2. Rendered crawler that could does exactly like most browsers you are using

To prevent all crawlers, you may want to put captcha on your site and it's annoying. But to allow a certain crawler, you may put some litle script to monitor and prevent the bad crawler as these following factors:
 1. Browser Agent
 2. How many pages the ip address could surf your site in a period of time
 3. Check whether the user can execute JavaScript ( not recommend because google may use renderless crawler too )

Answer (score 0):

If someone is out to steal your content they most likely won't care for nor obey the restrictions anyway.

Only option I can think of is knowing where they crawl from and block them from seeing the site at all.

Comment: yeah, it is true if I know which source they use to steal. But infact I do not know, so I am confusing how to apply white-list based access control (not black-list) for crawling systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex problem but sure it can be solved or minimized.

The perfect scenario is apply some complex IA techniques to identify patterns and keep blocking, banning them. You can treat it as a security threat to you business but keep in mind that you need to measure the trade-off here. For example, spend a lot money with a perfect solution don't justify or compensate if the primary reason is avoid waste of bandwidth.
See my point?

I know the question is too old but maybe someone can step-by here and see another point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to block crawlers IP Addresses.

**Crawlers Fresh IP Addresses -**

http://myip.ms/info/bots/Google_Bing_Yahoo_Facebook_etc_Bot_IP_Addresses.html